# React Native: Accessing JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, fetch

I'm using the `fetch` API to access the data and it turns out that when accessing this data which I have set in the data source it returns:

> **Warning**: **[TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluating 'response.data.onwardflights')]**

I am sure that I've fetched the data correctly as I have seen the data by printing it onto the console.

Here is the code for the same!

```
'use strict';

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text, ListView, ScrollView} from 'react-native';

const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2});

class BusList extends Component {

    constructor() {
    super();
    // const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([]),
      getData: []
    };
  }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadJSONData();
    }

    loadJSONData() {
        fetch('api')
          .then((response) => {
            this.setState({getData: response})
            this.setState({dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(response.data.onwardflights)})
            return response.json()
          })
          .then((responseJSON) => {
                    console.log(responseJSON)
              return this.setState({dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseJSON)});
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.warn(error);
          });
    }

    renderRow(rowData) {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{rowData.origin}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }

    render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <ListView
                dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
                enableEmptySections = {true}
                renderRow = {(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>}   
            />
        </View>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = BusList;
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the actual JSON as well?

Comment: @Pekka웃 The json response is very huge!!
Any alternate to post it in the comment itself?

Comment: Just the relevant bit then. The one around `response.data.onwardflights`

Comment: The data is complex and too big, :(
It goes far beyond the limit I could have simplified!

Comment: Well, when JavaScript tells you `response.data.onwardflights` doesn't exist, then it usually doesn't. Perhaps you have a level mismatch of some sort? How do you know the JSON is correct? If you're inspecting it or logging it to a console, can you show a small screen shot of the output?

Comment: {
 "data": {
  "returnflights": [],
  "onwardflights": [{
   "origin": "BOM",
   "rating": "1.3",
   "DepartureTime": "14:30",
   "cancellationPolicy": "0:12:100:0;12:24:50:0;24:-1:20:0",
   "cCount": 0,
   "farebasis": "0",
   "seat": "SL",
   "rowid": "some_id",
   "duration": "37h 30m",
   "qtype": "bus",
   "feedback": {},
   "skey": "some_skey",
   "busCondition": "nonac",
   "src_voyager_id": "4213513766539949483",
   "destination": "DEL"
  }]
 }
}

There are a lot more, but this is just the important part!

Comment: You're getting that when doing `console.log(response)` (or something similar)? Hmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the `response.data.onwardflights` will be `undefined` because you haven't invoked the `response.json()` prior to reading the data. Invoke the method first, and only then read the data. Please read [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json)